# SQL Table Output via LUA script

Tags: mysql, printing, lua

I'm looking for some help on a LUA script that should output the results of a table in a readable format.

This script just prints the results as a table reference:

```
database.open("provider=nis;database=nis;driver=none")

query = database.query("SELECT distinct cmcs.name, ms.schedule_name, mw.start_time, mw.end_time from MAINTENANCE_WINDOW mw INNER JOIN CM_DEVICE cmd on mw.dev_id = cmd.dev_id INNER JOIN CM_COMPUTER_SYSTEM cmcs on cmcs.cs_id = cmd.cs_id INNER JOIN MAINTENANCE_SCHEDULE ms on mw.schedule_id = ms.schedule_id where mw.end_time > GETDATE();")

print (query)
```

Output of above:

```
table:0x7fe8f40e6f00
```

I have the following script but it's not outputting what I am expecting to see:

```
database.open("provider=nis;database=nis;driver=none")

query = database.query("SELECT distinct cmcs.name, ms.schedule_name, mw.start_time, mw.end_time from MAINTENANCE_WINDOW mw INNER JOIN CM_DEVICE cmd on mw.dev_id = cmd.dev_id INNER JOIN CM_COMPUTER_SYSTEM cmcs on cmcs.cs_id = cmd.cs_id INNER JOIN MAINTENANCE_SCHEDULE ms on mw.schedule_id = ms.schedule_id where mw.end_time > GETDATE();")

if query == nil then
   print ("Query did not complete, or had no results")
else
   for idx,row in pairs (query) do
      printf("Hostname: %s \t IP: %s",row['name'],row['schedule_name'])
   end 
end
```

Here's a screenshot of the SQL output when ran on the SQL Server itself (if there is any output that is):

[image: SQL Output]

Comment: `printf` is not a lua function.

Comment: Which library are you using? If the library is returning a table you will have to loop through the key-value pairs and format it into the desired output, just like in the example that you provided.

You can also use some serialization library like serpent to output the table without manually looping through it.

Comment: You can download a library to print tables. I use [inspect.lua](https://github.com/kikito/inspect.lua).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Got it:

```
database.open("provider=nis;database=nis;driver=none")

function tdump(t)
       local function dmp(t, l, k)
     if type(t) == "table" then
       print(string.format("%s%s:", string.rep(" ", l*2), tostring(k)))
       for k, v in pairs(t) do
         dmp(v, l+1, k)
       end
     else
       print(string.format("%s%s:%s", string.rep(" ", l*2), tostring(k), tostring(t)))
     end
   end
 dmp(t, 1, "Maintenance Monitor")
         end 



--To OUTFILE
query = database.query("SELECT distinct cmcs.name, ms.schedule_name, mw.start_time, mw.end_time from MAINTENANCE_WINDOW mw INNER JOIN CM_DEVICE cmd on mw.dev_id = cmd.dev_id INNER JOIN CM_COMPUTER_SYSTEM cmcs on cmcs.cs_id = cmd.cs_id INNER JOIN MAINTENANCE_SCHEDULE ms on mw.schedule_id = ms.schedule_id where mw.end_time > GETDATE() INTO OUTFILE '/tmp/Maintenance.txt';")

tdump(query)
```

Hope it helps others!